# link leading to site page does not render

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I created a link (.url) in a Document Library that points to a site page within another site (.aspx).  If I click the link from the Document Library it redirects and opens the file fine.  If I click the link from a PnP Search Results, I get SharePoint Preview page with no contents and no redirect.

The faulty URL looks pretty standard https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME/SitePages/My-Page.aspx?csf=1&web=1&e=GUIDHERE

How do I troubleshoot this?

UPDATE: This appears to be a bug in PnP and is being discussed at https://github.com/microsoft-search/pnp-modern-search/issues/1761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I created a slot named `ShortcutUrl` to hold the value.  I then replaced this

```html
<a href="{{slot item @root.slots.PreviewUrl}}" target="_blank" style="color:{{@root.theme.semanticColors.link}}" data-interception="off" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{slot item @root.slots.Title}}
```

with

```html
{{#with (split (slot item @root.slots.ShortcutUrl) ',')}}
    <a href="{{[0]}}" target="_blank" data-interception="off" style="color:{{@root.theme.semanticColors.link}}" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{../Title}}</a>
{{/with}}
```

For some reason `{{slot item @root.slots.Title}}` did not render inside the `with` helper so I had to use `{{../Title}}`